# Display the values from Json into 2 text boxes

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a json array which by when i print it out it comes like this:

```
array(10) {
    [a]=> string(2) "11" 
    [b]=> string(1) "3" 
    [c]=> string(1) "4" 
    [d]=> string(1) "5" 
    [e]=> string(1) "6" 
    ["f"]=> string(1) "7"  
}
```

For display I have two boxes and I want to display both the results in the two different boxes.

Comment: Do you want to show same data in the two boxes

Comment: Added this syntax : var_dump($item[0]); after i used the foreach loop..